View other OP posts in the Staging Ground
During the beta tests in the Staging Ground, there were some cases where the author wrote a posted a copy of the question that bypassed the Staging Ground process. This user script shows me the questions of the same author while I'm reviewing a Staging Ground post. As it will be released next week if everything goes well, I'm now posting that script here.
The posts have the same format as the list of posts and are copied below the question to review (after comments).

Get it
You can view or install it on GitHub.
